# Back to top with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, anchor

I am building a mobile webapp with jquery mobile. Now I want to do a back to top action.
Normally you should do it like the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Body ID For Top Anchor Demo</title>
</head>

<!-- NOTICE: ID in Body Tag. -->
<body id="top">

<h1>
This Is My Demo
</h1>

<p style="margin-bottom: 3000px ;">
This paragraph has a huge ass bottom margin
so that the page will definitely scoll and
put the following link below the page fold.
</p>

<p>
<!--
This link will jump back up to the ID:top in
the document. Since that is the ID of the body
tag, this link will jump to the top of the page.
-->
<a href="#top">Back To Top</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But the # is in jquery mobile used for linking internal pages, so the method above doesn't work. Does anybody know how to do this properly?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 12):

jQuery Mobile has it's own `$.mobile.silentScroll()` function that scrolls `to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners.` (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html)

If you want to animate the scroll you can use `animate` to change the `scrollTop` property of the scroll-able page element (sometimes it's `<html>` sometimes it's `<body>`).

```
//delegate binding to only links that have the `.top` class
$(document).delegate('a.top', 'click', function () {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Here is a demo using `$.mobile.silentScroll()`: http://jsfiddle.net/XkjEE/2/

Here is a demo using `.animate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/XkjEE/1/

Docs:

- `scrollTop()`: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/
- `delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- `stop()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- `animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

## Update

You can set `data-ajax="false"` on a link or button widget to stop jQuery Mobile from hijacking the link clicks and stopping the default behavior of the links.

Make your link look something like this:

```
<a data-ajax="false" data-role="button" href="#top">TOP</a>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XkjEE/

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something similar today and came across this which might work http://jsfiddle.net/b4M66

The button only fades in once you start scrolling down the page and disappears once you return to the top of the page.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();    
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    });    
});​
```

CSS:

```
#toTop { position: fixed; bottom: 50px; right: 30px; width: 84px; background-color: #CCC; cursor: pointer; display: none; }​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toTop">Back to Top</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just try this:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```